# Nuances between 差し出す, 突き出す, and 出す

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I know 出す obviously has a broad set of meanings, 突き出す can mean "to hand over" or "to push out," and 差し出す can also mean "to submit," but when each are used roughly in the "hold/stick out" meaning, what are there nuances? For example, how do these differ:

> 手を出す
>
> 手を差し出す
>
> 手を突き出す

Or these:

> 首を出す
>
> 首を差し出す
>
> 首を突き出した

Beyond the nuances within these examples, are there certain words in this usage that only really work with some of them but not the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 6 phrases are possible in appropriate contexts.

- [手を出す](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%89%8B%E3%82%92%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99/#jn-148912) has several figurative meanings.
- 手を出す in the literal sense is close to 手を差し出す. But they are not completely interchangeable. E.g., 手を出して=*Give me your hands (I'll hand something over)*; 手を差し出して is not idiomatic.
- 首を出す only means the literal sense which is close to 首を突き出す. Both usually mean sticking out your head.
- 首を差し出す usually means figuratively *to sacrifice somebody* (cf. [差し出す＃2](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%B7%AE%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99/#jn-87792)). It may literally mean *to submit a severed head* in fictions.

---

FYI 顔を出す means figuratively *to drop by*. 顔を突き出す is used less idiomatically meaning the same as 首を突き出す. 顔を差し出す is not really possible.